# Recaptcha.widget is null and as a result does not render the form on recaptcha validation failure

Tags: java, javascript, recaptcha

Working on implementing recaptcha in a CMS integrated website. First is my HTMl body tag that invokes the javascript method to create a recaptcha on loading the body.

```
    <body onload="return reloadRecaptcha();">
```

Recaptcha appears below the form using the following code, Here is my js method that generates the recaptcha.

```
    function reloadRecaptcha() {
    console.log("@ reloadRecaptcha ");
    var publicKey = "";
    var strServername = location.hostname;

    if (strServername.indexOf("01") >= 0 || strServername.indexOf("02") >= 0 ){ 
        publicKey = "HARDCODED_INTERNAL_KEY1";
    } else {
        publicKey = "HARDCODED_PUBLIC_KEY2";
    }

    var div = "recap";

    if (!$("#message").is(":empty")) {
        console.log("@ if Recaptcha.create ");
        Recaptcha.create(publicKey,div,{theme: "red", callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
    } else {
        console.log("@ else Recaptcha.create ");
        Recaptcha.create(publicKey,div,{theme: "red"});
    }
    console.log("@ Exit reloadRecaptcha ");
    return false;
}
```

When I submit the form including the repatcha answer to the servlet which validates the answer and forwards back to the same form on error, I get the following error in my browser's console.

- In CHROME, error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" @ line recaptcha_ajax.js:112.
- In firefox, error message "TypeError: Recaptcha.widget is null" @ line recaptcha_ajax.js:112.

I have no clue why when I forward to the form jsp on error only I get this error and not during initial loading of the the form.

Code snippet of my server side code( a servlet):

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException  {
System.out.println("***** In the Captcha Validatation servlet**** ");
ReCaptchaImpl reCaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl();
String remoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();
String strServerUrl = request.getServerName().toLowerCase();
String strPrivateKey = "";
if ((strServerUrl.indexOf("01") >= 0) || (strServerUrl.indexOf("02") >= 0))
  strPrivateKey = getPropertyString("recaptcha.internal.privatekey");
else {
  strPrivateKey = getPropertyString("recaptcha.external.privatekey");
}
reCaptcha.setPrivateKey(strPrivateKey);
String challenge = request.getParameter("recaptcha_challenge_field");
String uresponse = request.getParameter("recaptcha_response_field");
ReCaptchaResponse reCaptchaResponse = reCaptcha.checkAnswer(remoteAddr, challenge, uresponse);
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
  String sessionId = session.getId();
  Map paramMap = new HashMap();
  for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    String key = (String)e.nextElement();
    String value = request.getParameter(key);
    paramMap.put(key, value);
  }
  session.setAttribute("paramMap", paramMap);
  if (reCaptchaResponse.isValid())
  {
    StringBuilder successUrl = new StringBuilder();
    successUrl.append(getPropertyString("recaptcha.validationsuccess.url"));
    successUrl.append("?evtvar=").append(request.getParameter("evtvar"));
    successUrl.append("&vgnextoid=").append(request.getParameter("vgnextoid"));
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(successUrl.toString());
    rd.forward(request, response);
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("***** reCaptchaResponse INVALID *** ");
    session.setAttribute("error1", getPropertyString("recaptcha.validationfailure.message"));
    System.out.println("SERVLET PATH --> " + request.getServletPath());
    String url_form = "/vgn-ext-templating/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=40289c7c6099f210VgnVCM100000268315acRCRD&vgnextfmt=default";
    System.out.println("Forwarding to the url after captcha validation  --> " + url_form);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(url_form);
    rd.forward(request, response);
  }
}}
```

What I perceive from the error is when the form reload to display the validation error message it could not find the div#recap

```
    <div id="recap" style="height:130px;"></div>
```

which is always present as part of my html, just below main form.

When I hit this url "http:///vgn-ext-templating/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=40289c7c6099f210VgnVCM100000268315acRCRD&vgnextfmt=default" directly from the browser the recaptcha and form appears as expected but the issue happens only on error and forwarding back to the form. Any help is appreciated.